# Convex and Preinvex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

While I'm reading some research papers on convexity and preinvex functions (which is a generalization of convexity) I noticed that sometimes authors assume that the domain of a convex (preinvex) function is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and sometimes it's subset of the positive real line, i.e., $K\subset [0,\infty)$. Is there a specific reason for this condition?

Among many articles, we have the following:

https://sigma.yildiz.edu.tr/storage/upload/pdfs/1635932447-en.pdf

and

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=http://www.pvamu.edu/mathematics/wp-content/uploads/sites/49/24_R1076_AAM_-Kashuri_AK_080417_V12_I2_Dec_2017.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj3herJj5mCAxVkh_0HHfDJA3wQFnoECBUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2u2iENj1MJGL8KxeXjIsOg